# Java awt EventListener asynchronous?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am working on a Java awt application. We currently have a class that implements runnable and calls render for the objects in our application. We also have Keyboard and Mouse listeners that call functions on various objects. I noticed a weird bug would occur when multiple keys were pressed rapidly, after some investigation it seems like the Event listeners are being called asynchronously separately from the main thread that is doing the rendering. Can anyone confirm that Java awt Event Listeners are called asynchronously, and suggest a possible solution?

```
public class Driver extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
    private boolean running = false;
    private Integer frames;
    private Thread thread;

    private Window window;
    private Mouse mouse;
    private Keyboard keyboard;

    /**
     *  Constructor of Driver
     *  Initiates Window, Mouse, Keyboard, handlers
     */
    public Driver()
    {
        window = new Window("Dominion", this);
        mouse = new Mouse(this);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this);
    }

    /**
     *  updates classes/variables that change per frame
     */
    public void tick() {
        //Framerate independent calls
    }


    /**
     *  Draws the game onto the window
     *  Calls other handler render to draw their parts
     */
    public void render()
    {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null)
        {
            this.createBufferStrategy(2);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        //Start Graphics

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, window.getWidth(), window.getHeight());

//Rest of rendering

        //End Graphics
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    /**
     *  Starts thread
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    /**
     *  Stops thread
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Important game function that calls the render and tick methods
     */
    public void run() {
        this.requestFocus();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        frames = 0;
        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if (running)
                render();

            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    /**
     * getter for window
     * @return window
     */
    public Window getWindow()
    {
        return window;
    }

    /**
     *  Starts up the whole Client side of things
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Driver();
    }
}
```

and mouse

```
public class Mouse implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener{
    private Driver d;

    /**
     * Creates a Mouse object
     * @param driver
     */
    public Mouse(Driver driver) {
        this.d = driver;
        d.addMouseListener(this);
        d.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        d.addMouseWheelListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Invoked when the mouse button has been clicked (pressed
     * and released) on a component.
     * @param e
     */
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    //Other methods cut out

}
```

Comment: You have it backwards. Its *your* application that does not properly sync with Swing. Swing does everything on its own thread (Event Disptach Thread = EDT). Doing things outside the EDT is one of the most common mistakes made that leads to spurious and hard to find bugs.

Comment: Oh ok, how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: Depends on what exactly the program is trying to do. You can either run your entire logic on the EDT (e.g. using Swing timer, or be strictly event driven), or if you need to use multiple threads you can use SwingUtilities.invoke(Later) to schedule updates in your GUI. Needless to say you *cannot* share data between threads without *some* form of synchronization. Things like rendering a model object that is potentially concurrently modified by another thread must be absolutely avoided.

Comment: OK, thanks. I think I can figure it out with Swing timer. If you want to put your comment in an answer I think I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing is strictly single threaded, everything Swing does happens on its own thread (the Event Dispatch Thread, aka EDT). This is not the main thread from where your java program starts. Few Swing methods can be safely called from outside the EDT (the javadocs are unfortunately not very explicit about this).

Most java GUI frameworks have the same restrictions (e.g. JavaFX uses a very similar approach).

As a result any listeners you attach to a Swing component do in fact run on the EDT. Painting, as far as the paint() method of Component is involved also happens on the EDT.

Depending on the requirements of the application, there are many approaches to adhere to Swings threading requirements while also satisfying the applications requirements.

The simplest case would be an entirely user input driven application (This is the kind where you just create a GUI and everything happens in response to an event caused by the user, e.g. mouse clicks or key presses). Since all code runs in listeners, its automatically called by Swing from the EDT and no threading issues occur. The downside is that you cannot execute long running methods, as they would block the EDT, resulting in an unresponsive GUI.

To get around the unresponsive GUI issue, long running work is scheduled outside the EDT, e.g. using the SwingWorker utility class. This approach works well for database accesses, file I/O or general computing that is done in response to user input.

For continously updating GUI's, like games above approaches are inadequate. For simple games, everything can be run on the EDT, there is e.g. SwingTimer to get regular "ticks" where application code is called by Swing from the EDT. Running all logic in that way avoids the threading issues.

For full blown games that need to cope with asynchronous tasks as well, e.g. networking, streaming of resources etc, a multithreaded approach is more suited. This makes things a lot more complex, as the application needs to make sure that data objects are passed from e.g. a loader thread to the GUI are properly synchronized and not modified by more than one thread at a time. The same goes for game state, while the game state is rendered it must not be modified. If game main thread and rendering need to be asynchronous (e.g. realtime game logic that cannot wait if rendering is slow), the main game thread may need to make snapshot copies to pass game state for rendering.

Thats just a very rough outline of ways you can go :)

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on the `EDT`.